# Gwibber does not respect proxy settings

Tags: proxy, gwibber

Is there any way to make Gwibber respect the system proxy settings? Right now, if I try setting up a Facebook account from the "Broadcast Accounts..." option, it comes back with an "unable to load page" error.

[image: broadcast accounts facebook error message]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug documented in launchpad:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/gwibber/+bug/259830

Comment: it has been a bug for a few years now. and its a problem systemwide. A lot of conflicting proxy sources...

Answer (score -1):

You can use "All Settings -> Network -> Network Proxy -> Manual" and then after setting the desired proxy, "Apply System Wide". This way all Ubuntu's network traffic including Gwibber's will tunnel through your desired proxy.

Comment: Have you personally verified this with the current version of Ubuntu and Gwibber? I'm asking because Pisu's answer above links to the Launchpad bug documenting this issue, and it's still open there.

Comment: I have this problem too. Gwibber and Empathy doesn’t follow Ubuntu proxy settings.